# Remove events from the panel's calendar indicator

Tags: unity, evolution, calendar

How can I remove calendar events from unity Panel? I installed `evolution` and imported an `.ics` archive to test. After removing the calendar from evolution and remove evolution, the calendar events are still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calendar is stored in `~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar.ics`

If you simply remove the calendar, log out and back in, it should be fixed.

Comment: I can`t believe i didn`t try it before . The easiest way.